# Assigning Field value as empty- exacttarget AMP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

m trying to UPDATE :

```
IF @usmsopt == "False" THEN
  SET @smsoptoutdate = CURRENT DATE
ELSE
  SET @smsoptoutdate = CLEAR THE DATE

ENDIF
```

with the following AMP:

```
IF @usmsopt == "False" THEN
  SET @smsoptoutdate = Now()
ELSE
 SET @smsoptoutdate = ""
ENDIF
```

BUT WHEN  `@usmsopt == "True"` then instead of emptying the field i get `'1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM'` value

any idea??

How about if i do like below ??: based on this:https://code.exacttarget.com/question/forcing-date-field-remain-null

```
IF @usmsopt == "False" THEN

  SET @smsoptoutdate = Now()

ELSE

 ENDIF
```

THE ABOVE (1) WORKED WELL FOR ME FOR CREATE OPERATION . BUT AM TRYING TO WORK STILL ON UPDATE WITHOUT TRYING TO CHANGE THE DATE FIELD AS TEXT IN DE . BASED ON THE LINK : https://code.exacttarget.com/question/end-date-field-getting-default-value

DOES THE FOLLOWING WORK (update an existing value to NULL):

```
/* to do : here i need to clear the old optout date */
ELSEIF @currentsmsopt == "True" AND @presmsopt =="False" THEN
IF NOT EMPTY(@presmsoptdt) THEN 
Var @deo
Set @deo = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "DATA EXTENSION")
/*   erase the exsting value */
Var @smsoptoutdateproperty
Set @smsoptoutdateproperty = CreateObject("NullAPIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@enddateproperty, "Name", "smsoptoutdt")

AddObjectArrayItem(@deo, "Properties", @smsoptoutdateproperty)

SET @result = UpsertData("DATA EXTENSION", 1, "custid", @ucustid, "emailaddress", @uemailaddress, "FirstName", @ufirstname, "LastName", @ulastname, "Zip", @uzip, "Mobile", @mobile1, "Phone", @phone, "Country", @ucountry, "Wants_email", @uemailopt, "Wants_sms", @currentsmsopt, "Add_Edit_Date", @editdt, "Optoutdate_sms", @smsoptoutdt, "Optoutdate_email", @emailoptoutdt, "Mobilecode", @countrycode, "Locale", @ulocale, "Signup", @signupdt, "Source", @source, "SubscriberKey", @friendkey)
ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 3):

The default time stamp in a data extension is the `'1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM'` value you are seeing.

In order to not get that, you would need to have the field set to a `text` field. This should correct your issue.  The data will still be recognized in other parts of the program as a date, even though the field type is not set to `date`.

Comment: Any workaround solution without touching the DE field type ??

Comment: No,  unfortunately.

Comment: How about if i try sth like above ? is it acceptable??

Comment: a moment to have a look on this?

Comment: @Jack85 - that should work for you. Give it a shot and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It worked ... cool.. thx

Comment: I did work but for Create Operation only but not for update when there is date already, it doesn't clear it .For create, if there is no date then the filed gets empty rather than default timestamp ('1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM').

Comment: @Timothy/ @kelly : any pointers with the code?

Comment: any pointers ? thx.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an old post but updating can be accomplished by pulling a reference value via a lookup then using that value to set the date in a target DE.

```
%%[
/* Lookup reference null value of dateStamp from ID=1 */
SET @n = Lookup('NullDateTest', 'dateStamp', 'ID', '1')
/* show that ID 2 has a value */
SET @n2 = Lookup('NullDateTest', 'dateStamp', 'ID', '2')
OUTPUT(concat("n1: ",@n, " n2: ", @n2, "<br>"))
]%%

%%[
/* show updated row count */

OUTPUT(UpdateData('NullDateTest', 1, 'ID', '2', 'dateStamp', @n))

]%%

%%[
/* show final values where date has been updated to null */
SET @n3 = Lookup('NullDateTest', 'dateStamp', 'ID', '1')
/* Used a lookup rows to prevent cached result of a lookup */
SET @n4 = Field(Row(LookupRows('NullDateTest', 'ID', '2'), 1), 'dateStamp')
OUTPUT(concat("<br>n3: ",@n3, " n4: ", @n4))
]%%
```

Oddly you cannot use a similar tactic directly in SSJS, perhaps because the way the concept of null works in SSJS but you can use an AMPscript var to perform the same action in SSJS.

```
%%[
/** reference null value pulled into Variable **/
SET @n = Lookup('NullDateTest', 'dateStamp', 'ID', '1')
]%%
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1");
var DE = DataExtension.Init("NullDateTest");
DE.Rows.Update({dateStamp:Variable.GetValue("@n")}, ["ID"], ["2"]);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Brandt!  This does work and accomplished my requested task.

Note (which may not be surprising): some functions performed could alter the value being written back.

Example, if you try to assign the value from an iif statement, like:
set @datestamp = iif (1==1, field(@row,'datestamp'), @datestamp))

This will upsert or update back to the DE with 1/1/1900.

"If, then" will not cause it when it is doing its evaluation.

Just something to be aware.